# Error updating record in Android with sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

implementing an update of a record in a database sqlite gives me this error that I leave.
I would appreciate some help.
I have reviewed close connections and open but does not change the error.
The SDK is motodevstudio 3 and "Android 2.2."

```
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.ftair/com.ftair.Infraccion}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.ftair/databases/daastm already closed
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3128)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.ftair/databases/daastm.jpg already closed
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:237)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.requery(SQLiteQuery.java:145)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.requery(SQLiteCursor.java:531)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:3795)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performRestartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3477)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:160)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchResume(LocalActivityManager.java:518)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onResume(ActivityGroup.java:58)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
11-30 09:40:34.052: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2646):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535908/android-sqlite-sqliteopenhelper-error-illegalstateexception-db-already-clo) link it might help you out.

Comment: can you post the code/class that is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Open your database directly before you try and create/read/update/delete and close it when you finish with it.  This should stop the error.  It's possible that even if this activity leaves the database open say from `onStart` to `onStop`  that another activity on the activity stack is closing the database.